# Adding a new rule into a Security Group

Tags: filab

When adding a new rule to a security group, is it needed to restart the
instance to the new rule take effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you forgot to assign a security group rule to the security group, but
you created it (the security group) and assigned it to the instance. There is no
problem to update the security group with the new rule. After it, you could
use it without no need to restart the instance.

For example, you can find in port 22, without it, you cannot access
 your instance via ssh. You need to add the rule and then you can access the instance via ssh.