# No Connection to FI-LAB VM (even unable to ping)

Tags: fiware, filab

As the title says i am trying to test out the FI-LAB.
For that purpose i already created a VM following a tutorial from a FI-WARE Webinar.

I associated a floating IP to the VM, created a KeyPair for it (and assigned it of course) and opened Port 22 with a Security Group for this VM.

However I can not connect it with VM display on the Lab-Site (nothing ever happens and even if i am lucky enough to get a Window for it, it stays grey).

After reading on stackoverflow and some googlesearches i set up a new KeyPair for that VM, downloaded the keyfile, transformed it to a .ppk with puttygen and tried connecting to the VM with Putty.
However I get a 'Connection refused' error when trying to connect via Putty.

Guessing this might be caused by my companies proxy (maybe blocking the application when connecting to the internet), i tried to ping the VM via command-line.

I tried both the floating and the initial IP of that VM in my command-line and both ran out with a time-out.

So my question: Am i missing something? Did someone else have this problem and might have a solution?

P.S. I created multiple VMs (sometimes from Images, sometimes blank new ones) and neither did work.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I just tried to ping the lab.fi-ware.org site and the cloud.lab.fi-ware.org site...both pings timed out but i can open it in all my web browsers...maybe this might help someone understand the problem

EDIT 2: I now tried it with my phone...i can ping the lab-server from my phone but i still can not ping the floating ip of my VM on any device

EDIT 3: It is fixed...it was caused by a security rule our company recently setup...no problems with FI-WARE :)

Comment: How about to connect from a client on the network where your machine with FI-LAB VM is connected. You may be able to avoid problems about companies proxy by connecting server and client in a network segment.

Comment: @Fumu7 First, thank you for answering. But how could i do that? The VM is on the fi-lab servers in Spain if i understood that corretctly...sorry if i got something wrong but i am a total newbie to fi-ware. How should i get a Client working in their network environment?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems accessing FI-WARE Lab VM because I didn't do a creation of VM and all the preparatory actions in right order - so the security rule (i.e. opening port 22) wasn't acknowledged by VM until I restarted the instance.

For the matter of when the restart is needed after adding security rule see [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956121/adding-a-new-rule-into-a-security-group).

But as far as this could be a proxy issue, I'm afraid there is not much you can do without asking your admin for help. Small chances, but you can try different ports, like mentioned in [This question's accepted answer](https://superuser.com/questions/351560/use-putty-behind-a-proxy).

But, I hope that it was just a FI-WARE temporary bug, and that you are in :).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I talked to our admins and it was indeed a problem with our security configurations...it is fixed now but thanks anyway :)